# Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus - a question concerning a possible typo

Tags: stochastic-processes, probability

In page 143 of Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus of Karatzas and Shreve one reads:

[image]

This inequality is true, However, to be meaningfull shouldn't it be 
$$\alpha^2 |X_t(\omega)|^2 f_1(t,\omega)+ 2 \alpha |X_t(\omega)Y_t(\omega)|f_3(t,\omega) + |Y_t(\omega)|^2 f_2(t,\omega) \geq 0 $$
Instead of 
$$\alpha^2 |X_t(\omega)|^2 f_1(t,\omega)+ 2 \alpha |X_t(\omega)Y_t(\omega)||f_3(t,\omega)| + |Y_t(\omega)|^2 f_2(t,\omega) \geq 0 $$

This seems the case for me but I am not sure,

To make my point clearer, I'd like to add some context:

[image]

[image]